# Creating a Deck of Cards using an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I know this has been asked by many people before (and I looked around quite a bit before coming here), but I can't seem to figure out how to fix my code.  My task is to make a static makeDeck method that returns an ArrayList containing the 52 cards of a standard deck of cards.  I'm fairly new to ArrayLists, so I'm not entirely sure if I'm initializing my ArrayList makeDeck correctly.  This is what I have so far:

```
    public class Card 
    { 
      private String mySuit; 
      private int myValue; 

      public Card( String suit, int value ) 
      { 
        mySuit = suit; 
        myValue = value; 
      } 

      public String name() 
      { 
        String[] cardNames =  
          { 
            "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", 
            "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", 
            "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" 
          }; 

        return cardNames[ myValue - 2 ] + " of " + mySuit; 
      } 
    } 

    public class MainClass 
    { 
      public static void displayCards( ArrayList<Card> a ) 
      { 
        int i; 
        System.out.println( "Size is " + a.size() ); 
        for ( i = 0 ; i < a.size() ; i++ ) 
        { 
          Card c = a.get( i ); 
          System.out.println( "#" + (i+1) + ": " + c.name() ); 
        } 
      } 

    public static ArrayList<Card> makeDeck()
    {
      ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
      String[] cardNames =  
          { 
            "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", 
            "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", 
            "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" 
          }; 
      String[] suits = { "spades", "hearts", "diamonds", "clubs"  }; 

            for (int a=0; a<=cardNames.length(); a++)
            {
                for (int b=0; b<= suits.length(); b++)
                 {
                   cards.add(new Card(cardNames[a], suits[b]));  //I've noticed many people use this to add the card names and suits to the cards ArrayList, and it gives me an error of not being able to turn suits[b] into an integer, so I'm confused as to how it worked for others  

                 }
            }
return cards;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
      System.out.println(makeDeck());
    }
```

If someone could please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong, I would be very grateful.  Thank you!

Comment: What are you seeing?

Comment: add return cards at the end of the makeDeck function

Comment: This is my current error: MainClass.java:31: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int 

               cards.add(new Card(cardNames[a], suits[b]));
but I'm sure there are others as well.

Comment: Please provide `Card` class implementaion. For me `Card` constructor is not accepting Integer as asecond parameter. Moreover use `suits.lenght`.

Comment: Using good IDE should work here...

Comment: @bartektartanus My class is using eIMACS, and it's terrible.  It's fill-in-the-blank style so I can't go back and edit prior work once it's submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing two Strings to your `Card` constructor. Before you editted out the code of the `Card` class, I saw that your constructor expects a String and an int. That's why the constructor call doesn't compile.

In addition, you forgot to return a value in your `makeDeck()` method, and your `cards` list is local to that method, so you can't access it from your main method, and you don't have a `cards()` method anyway.

Your main method should be :

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
  System.out.println(makeDeck());
}
```

Your `makeDeck()` should have a `return cards;` statement in its last line.

And you should either change the constructor of your `Card` class or change the argumnets you are passing to it.

With the current implementation of your Card class, you should probably change the Card creation loop to :

```
    for (int a=0; a < suits.length; a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b< 13 ; b++)
         {
           cards.add(new Card(suits[a],b));  
         }
    }
```

You'll probably have to change the `name()` method of `Card` though.

Comment: The IDE I'm using is a sort-of Fill-in-the-blank style so I can't change anything from the Card constructor.  Therefore, how would I change the int it's expecting to a String?

Comment: @MichaelWendel see my edit. You have to pass an int instead of a String. And the suit name should be the first parameter.

Comment: I've added in your last edit and now it's telling me it can't find the symbol for suits.length().  Also, how would I be able to pass an int without editing the Card class, because I can't do that with the website I'm using?

Comment: @MichaelWendel It's a typo. Should be suits.length. Sorry

Comment: @MichaelWendel Well, since the `name()` method uses `cardNames[ myValue - 2 ]` to get the card name based on its index, you have to pass to the constructor values between 2 and 14, so you can change the loop to `for (int b=2; b< 15 ; b++)`

Comment: Sorry to keep pestering you, but the issue is that it's now outputting this: [Card@15db9742, Card@6d06d69c, Card@7852e922...

Comment: @MichaelWendel That means Card doesn't override `toString`. If you can't change the code of `Card` and you want something else to be printed, you'll have to iterate over the cards yourself, and print whatever you want for each card.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `makeDeck()` return `cards`.  Also in your main print statement you meet to call `makeDeck()` instead of `cards()`

In regards to your error `string cannot be converted to int` you need to do one of two things:

1) Change the Card class constructor to take in two strings:

```
Public Card(string value, string suit)
```

And change `int myValue` to `string myValue`

2) Change your cardName array to be `int` instead of `string`. You could alternatively Ignore `cardNames` all together and change you insert to the following:

```
cards.add(new Card(suits[b], a+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

add `return` statement that will return your array list.

```
public static ArrayList<Card> makeDeck()
    {
      ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
      String[] cardNames =  
          { 
            "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", 
            "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", 
            "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" 
          }; 
      String[] suits = { "spades", "hearts", "diamonds", "clubs"  }; 

            for (int a=0; a<=12; a++)
            {
                for (int b=0; b<=3; b++)
                 {
                   cards.add(new Card(cardNames[a], suits[b]));  //I've noticed many people use this to add the card names and suits to the cards ArrayList, and it gives me an error of not being able to turn suits[b] into an integer, so I'm confused as to how it worked for others  

                 }
            }
    return cards;
    }
```

call `makeDeck()` from your main method.

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
  ArrayList<Card> cards = makeDeck();

 for(Card c : cards){
   System.out.println("You can print card member variables here");
 } 

}
```

Comment: This code will not compile. The constructor expects an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to `return` at the end of your method,

```
public static ArrayList<Card> makeDeck()
{
  ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
  String[] cardNames =  
      { 
        "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", 
        "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", 
        "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" 
      }; 
  String[] suits = { "spades", "hearts", "diamonds", "clubs"  }; 

        for (int a=0; a<=12; a++)
        {
            for (int b=0; b<=3; b++)
             {
               cards.add(new Card(cardNames[a], b)); // <-- if the second Card 
               //                        parameter whould be an int.
             }
        }
    return cards;
}
```

And you should be calling `makeDeck()` not `cards()`

```
System.out.println(makeDeck());
```